# How to pass the value from function inside function to main module?

Tags: python, tkinter

i need help for below codes, I trying to create a software using tkinter and i have a issue on passing the value from inside function inside sub function to main module. how to get the return result use in main module and insert in mylist.

Here's the codes:
**main module: test.py**

```
from button_screener import screener
```

button created to open screen. command = screener

```
mylist = [ ]                                                             
mylist.insert(END, result)`
```

**sub module: button_screener**

```
def screener():
    code.... (create tkinter layout code)
    OK_button created to execute function execute() - command = execute

    def execute():
       code... after several calculation..get result below
       result = list [a,b,c]
       return result
```

Needs help and let me know if needed further clarifications.

Thank you

Comment: If those functions are triggered by buttons, then the result returned will be discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those functions are executed by a button click, whatever returned from those functions will be discarded.

As the result you want to return is a `list`, you can pass the required `list` variable to `screener()` as an argument which will be updated inside the function.

Below is a simple example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def screener(result):
    def execute():
        # do some calculation
        a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
        # then update result
        result[:] = [a, b, c]
        win.destroy()

    win = tk.Toplevel()
    tk.Button(win, text='OK', command=execute).pack(padx=50, pady=50)
    win.grab_set()


mylist = []

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text='Sceener', command=lambda:screener(mylist)).pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Show', command=lambda:print(mylist)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i got your idea :D THANKS BRO!

Comment: hi @acw1668 how about if i wan to pass the value from class in 2nd module to main window module. is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

When you call a new function, you can think of it as creating a stack (of operations).
The function that is called latest will be at the top of the stack, and once it finishes executing it will **return** back to the calling function (and also return any value if you have specified in the return statement).

which means : when you do **return result** in your execute() function, it will provide that result to it's calling function : screener()

since you are calling screener() from your main module, you should capture the output of execute() in screener(), and then return that to the screener() 's calling function - which is main.

```
def screener():
    code.... (create tkinter layout code)
    #OK_button created to execute function execute() - command = execute


    def execute():
       code... after several calculation..get result below
       result = list [a,b,c]
       return result

    result_from_execute = execute() #capturing response from execute()
    return result_from_execute #return the result to the main module
```

Comment: but if I return the result from the screener function itself and use in main module, i will execute all the tkinter layout design too which i do not wish to happen

Comment: this is the sequence of the running codes, i create the button to call the screen pop out in the main module # command = Buttonscreener.screener. and in the sub module, i would like to pass the value from function inside function directly to the main module.. is that possible to do that? or i should try to pull out from screener function and align with the screener function, so i can get the data from it and plug into main module.. hmmm......

Comment: i tried pull out from main function but i have some value become not declarable as i used the variable to do the calculation inside that main function.. hmmm

Comment: The answer by @acw1668 makes sense then.  Pass the mutable object : myList to the screener and execute functions, and update it in over there. You will be able to see those updates when u use this object in main after that.